# virtual box windows 7 screen size problems

Tags: virtualbox

I have windows 7 installed in virtual box with ubuntu 14.04. I cannot get it into full screen...there is at least 3 inches of black on both side and an inch at the top and bottom. I already installed guest additions and that had no effect. Does anyone know a fix?

Answer (score 0):

This is usually caused when the VM is running at a lower resolution than the host display. If guest additions are installed I would restart the VM then try to adjust the resolution within the VM to that of the display.

Comment: I tried to change the resolution within the virtual Windows 7 and the resolution setting for the guest screen is lower than the host but there is not an option to increase it as much as the host screen. In other words the max resolution option is lower for the guest. I have no clue how to change that.